# C# / .NET - How to allow a "custom" Root-CA for HTTPS in my application (only)?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, x509certificate

Okay, here is what I need to do:

My application, written in C# (.NET Framework 4.5), needs to communicate with our server via HTTPS. Our server uses a TLS/SSL certificate issued by our own Root-CA. That Root-CA, while perfectly trusted by my application, is **not** installed in the system's "trusted root" certificate store. So, without further work, C# refuses to contact the server, because the server's certificate cannot be validated - as expected. Note: We cannot use a Root-CA already installed in the system.

What can I do to allow my application to (securely) contact our server? I know that C# provides classes to install our Root-CA certificate into the *system's* certificate store as a "trusted root". That's **not** what we want to do! That's because **(a)** it shows an alarming (and way too technical) warning to the user, and because **(b)** it would effect other applications too - which we don't want or need.

So what I need is something that tells C#/.NET to use a "custom" (i.e. *application-specific*) set of certificates - instead of the system-wide certificate store - to validate the chain of the server certificate. The whole certificate chain still needs to be validated properly (including revocation lists!). Only our Root-CA needs to be accepted as a "trusted" root  for **my** application.

What would be the best way to do this?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

---

BTW: I found out that I can use `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` to install my own certificate validation function. This *does* work. But that method isn't good, because now I need to do the **whole** certificate validation *manually* in my own code. However, I do **not** want to re-implement the whole certificate verification process (e.g. downloading and checking CRL's etc), which is already implemented (and tested) in .NET Framework. It's like re-inventing the wheel and can never be tested as thoroughly as the .NET implementation that already exists.

Answer (score 26):

The `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` delegate is the right way to your solution. However, I would use a different behavior in the delegate, than suggested by Olivier. That's why: too many irrelevant checks are performed and relevant are not.

So, look at the issue in details:

At first, we shall consider the scenario when your service uses legitimate certificate purchased from commercial CA (this may not be the case right now, but may be in some future). This means that if `sslPolicyErrors` parameter has `None` flag presented, immediately return `True`, the certificate is valid and there are no obvious reasons to reject it. This step is necessary only if the following your statement is NOT strict:

> Only our Root-CA needs to be accepted as a "trusted" root for my application.

otherwise, ignore first step.

Let's assume, the service still uses certificate from private and untrusted CA. In this case we have to handle errors which are not related to certificate chain and are specific only to SSL session. Thus, when the `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` delegate is called, we shall ensure that `RemoteCertificateNameMismatch` and `RemoteCertificateNotAvailable` flags are not presented in the `sslPolicyErrors` parameter. If any of them presented, we shall reject connection without additional checks.

Let's assume that none of these flags presented. At this point we correctly handled SSL-specific errors and only certificate chain may have issues.

If we reach this far, we can claim that `sslPolicyErrors` parameter contains `RemoteCertificateChainErrors` flag. This can mean everything and we have to make additional checks. Your root CA certificate is a constant. This means that we can examine root certificate in the `chain` parameter and compare it with our constant (Root CA certificate's thumbprint, for example). If comparison fails, we immediately reject the certificate, because it is not your's and there are no obvious reasons to trust certificate issued by an unknown CA and which may have other chain issues.

If comparison succeeds, then we reached the case we have to handle carefully and properly. We have to execute another instance of certificate chaining engine and instruct it to collect any chain issues, except `UntrustedRoot` error only. This means that if SSL certificate has other issues (RevocationOffline, validity, policy errors for example) we will know about that and will reject this certificate.

The code below is a programmatical implementation of many words above:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace MyNamespace {
    class MyClass {
        Boolean ServerCertificateValidationCallback(Object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) {
            String rootCAThumbprint = ""; // write your code to get your CA's thumbprint

            // remove this line if commercial CAs are not allowed to issue certificate for your service.
            if ((sslPolicyErrors & (SslPolicyErrors.None)) > 0) { return true; }

            if (
                (sslPolicyErrors & (SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch)) > 0 ||
                (sslPolicyErrors & (SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable)) > 0
            ) { return false; }
            // get last chain element that should contain root CA certificate
            // but this may not be the case in partial chains
            X509Certificate2 projectedRootCert = chain.ChainElements[chain.ChainElements.Count - 1].Certificate;
            if (projectedRootCert.Thumbprint != rootCAThumbprint) {
                return false;
            }
            // execute certificate chaining engine and ignore only "UntrustedRoot" error
            X509Chain customChain = new X509Chain {
                ChainPolicy = {
                    VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority
                }
            };
            Boolean retValue = customChain.Build(chain.ChainElements[0].Certificate);
            // RELEASE unmanaged resources behind X509Chain class.
            customChain.Reset();
            return retValue;
        }
    }
}
```

This method (named delegate) can be attached to `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`. The code might be compacted (combine multiple IF's in one IF statement, for example), I used verbose version to reflect textual logic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I think what you describe makes a lot of sense. Using a "custom" `X509Chain` with `AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority` flag is actually what I was looking for. It defers most checks to the "framework". But I have to ask: Are you absolutely sure that Build() would fail here, if CRL could not be found or CRL indicated our "built-in" Root-Cert as revoked? While our "built-in" Root-Cert is fully trusted now, we need to be able to revoke it in the future - for whatever reason.

Comment: Root CA revocation is not supported by RFC 5280 and no compliant chaining engine support this.

Comment: if you wish to replace your Root CA certificate, then change `rootCAThumbprint` variable in the code to a new value. This will automatically invalidate your previous root CA certificate in the logic.

Comment: Okay, I can update the RootCA thumbprint via software update. But "old" software version also need to reject the "old" certificate, as soon as it has been revoked. Sure, the CRL which revokes the RootCA would have to be signed by the RootCA itself - which is now revoked. This may seem paradox. But we have to keep the following in mind: If the RootCA signs its own revocation, we know for sure that something is seriously wrong. Somebody who has stolen the Root's private key certainly would never do this - so the RootCA revocation (if it ever exists) has to be legit.

Comment: CryptoGuy 19, you are referring to RFC 5280. Can you tell me where exactly this RFC says that Root CA certificates cannot be revoked at all? Or is this your own conclusion? I had a look at the RFC but could not find this information. Thank you!

Comment: Had a look? The document is quite large and complex and it is not enough to "had a look at the RFC". You need to read it carefully, line by line, instead. §6.1 states: "When the trust anchor is provided in the form of a self-signed certificate, this self-signed certificate is not included as part of the prospective certification path.". This means that root CA certificate is not checked for revocation (because is not included in the prospective certification path).

Comment: Moreover, this conslusion is very logical: Root CA signs its own CRL. If this certificate appears in the CRL, you encounter a chicken and egg problem: CRL (signed by root CA certificate) states that root CA certificate is revoked. If it is revoked, then we cannot guarantee CRL integrity, as the result we cannot rely on CRL information. Then we can conclude that root CA certificate is not necessary revoked (bacause CRL signature validation fails).

Comment: Well, I meant that I searched the RFC for a statement about Root-CA validation, not that I read it completely ;-) Anyway, there is a "chicken and egg" problem, yes. BUT: If somebody successfully created a CRL that revokes the Root CA's cert *and* that has a valid signature, that entity *must* be in possession of the Root CA's private key. This can only mean two things: (1) The legitimate owner intentionally revoked his own Root-CA or (2) somebody has stolen the private key and created a "fake" CRL. In both cases, the Root CA must no longer be trusted. Or am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: "If somebody successfully created a CRL that revokes the Root CA's cert and that has a valid signature" this means that your root CA is compromised, otherwise, an attacker won't be able to create valid signature on CRL. As I said, root CA revocation is undefined and you really should take care on root CA security.

Comment: Exactly, *"if somebody successfully created a CRL that revokes the Root CA's cert and that has a valid signature"*, then we have a clear indication that Root-CA is compromised. Either that, or the legitimate owner of the Root-CA decided to officially revoke his Root-CA for some reason. It doesn't really matter - in both case we *have* to reject the Root-CA from now on. If the RFC leaves this case "undefined" and if there's nothing in .NET to properly handle this case, then we need to find a fix...

Comment: if you want to reject your root CA, then clear thumbprint value in the code (or update the source from which the thumbprint is retrieved). There is nothing else I can suggest.

Comment: How about 
            ```customChain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(trustedCert);``` ?

Comment: Possibly the line

`    // RELEASE unmanaged resources behind X509Chain class.
    chain.Reset();`

Should be:

`    // RELEASE unmanaged resources behind X509Chain class.
    customChain.Reset();`

?

Comment: Umm...  SslPolicyErrors.None == 0 in System.dll v4.0.0.0, Doesn't that mean that (sslPolicyErrors & (SslPolicyErrors.None)) is -always- 0?

Answer (score 7):

You can use that callback and don't have to reinvent the wheel.

If you take a closer look, the [callback has multiple parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback.aspx):

```
public delegate bool RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(
    object sender,
    X509Certificate certificate,
    X509Chain chain,
    SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors
)
```

The parameters are the result of the check through the .Net implementation. You can e.g. check if the only problem is the missing root CA by using the following code:

```
// Check if the only error of the chain is the missing root CA,
// otherwise reject the given certificate.
if (chain.ChainStatus.Any(statusFlags => statusFlags.Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot))
    return false;
```

It will iterate through the whole chain and checks all states. If any is anything else then untrusted root (beware: the enum has a flags attribute) we fail. But if the only *bad thing* is the not trusted root, you can take it.

But another problem you get now, is that you know that this certificate has an untrusted root, but you don't know if that is really your certificate (or any other).

To ensure this, you have to read the public part of your server certificate that you have stored with your application and compare it to the given chain:

```
// Read CA certificate from file.
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
var certificateAuthority = new X509Certificate(_ServerCertificateLocation);
var caEffectiveDate = DateTime.Parse(certificateAuthority.GetEffectiveDateString());
var caExpirationDate = DateTime.Parse(certificateAuthority.GetExpirationDateString());

// Check if CA certificate is valid.
if (now <= caEffectiveDate
    || now > caExpirationDate)
    return false;

// Check if CA certificate is available in the chain.
return chain.ChainElements.Cast<X509ChainElement>()
                          .Select(element => element.Certificate)
                          .Where(chainCertificate => chainCertificate.Subject == certificateAuthority.Subject)
                          .Where(chainCertificate => chainCertificate.GetRawCertData().SequenceEqual(certificateAuthority.GetRawCertData()))
                          .Any();
```

Maybe it would be wise to add a fast exit at the beginning of the function, if the server delivers a certificate that is signed by an installed root CA (which is maybe not yours!):

```
if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None
    && chain.ChainStatus.All(statusFlags => statusFlags.Status == X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError))
    return true;
```

Also if desired (depending on your needs) you can allow or disallow to use a certificate, where the server name and certificate name doesn't match. This happens, e.g. if the certificate was made for *localhost* and you access the server from a different machine. Or within a intranet you only use `http://myserver` instead of `http://myserver.domain.com`, but the certificate was made on the full qualified name (or vice versa):

```
if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch)
    return false;
```

And that's it. You still rely on the default implementation and only additionally check your parts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But what you are doing is what I meant with "having to validate the certificate manually". You have to implement various checks yourself and cannot be sure you've done it correct (and complete). Actually, your code doesn't check for CRL's yet. If there is no other way, we might need to go that route. But I'd much prefer a solution like "validate the server's certificate as usual, but also treat this particular X509 cert as a trusted root (as if it was in the system's 'trusted root' store)". Can I use `X509Chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore` somehow? Don't know where to set it!

Comment: @dtr84, "You have to implement various checks yourself and cannot be sure you've done it correct (and complete)". Yep, this solution barely can contend with RFC5280 validation rules..